# how to apply mongo db update operators as $inc in spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

All I want to do is a simple query using spring boot and mongodb but I can't find resources online, update query to increment frequency field by one given searchString or create a new document if searchString is not found.

```
@Query("{'searchString': ?0 } , {'$inc' : {'frequency':1}} ")
public void incFreq(String query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope you use **spring-data-mongodb**. Since you haven't mentioned about the Document class, I assume it as **Person.class**

First you `@Autowire` the **MongoTemplate** in the service implementation.

```
@Autowire
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Then what you can do is, you can call a query like following,

```
public void incFreq(String given_str){
    Query query=new Query(Criteria.where("searchString ").is("given_str"));
    Person person=mongoTemplate.find(query,Person.class);

    if(person!=null){
        Update update=new Update().inc("frequency",1)
        UpdateResult result=mongoTemplate.updateOne(query,update,Person.class);
        // bu using the result, you can see modifiedCount(),matchCount()
    }else{
        // insert query
    }
}
```

If you going to use JPA methods, then

```
public void incFreq(String given_str){
    Optional<Person> p=personRepository.findBySearchString(String given_str);
    if(p.isPresent()){
        p.get().setFrequency(p.get().getFrequency()+1);
        personRepository.save(p);
    }else{
        Person p=new Person();
        p.setName("some name");
        p.setFrequency(1);
        personRepository.save(p);
    }
}
```

Refer [Spring data mongodb](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-update)

Comment: I totally agree with both solutions but the problem with these solutions that I will hit the database twice first for finding then for updating, is there anyway to use upsert update.

Comment: Ohh, i thought that you're a beginner, may be i wasted time of both of us :'(. Just refer `$setOnInsert` and `upsert`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
   MongoTemplete mongotemplate;

Update update = new Update();

    Query query = new Query();
    update.inc("listPrice",productItem.getListPrice());
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query,update,ProductCatalogItem.class);

    

#"listPrice" : for which you wanna use $inc.
#productItem : instance of your class
```

Comment: Please add some context to help future visitors to the site understand how to use your answer. This is covered in [answer].